# sw-precache push notification listener

Tags: javascript, service-worker, sw-precache

I would like to create my first PWA app and I want to use `sw-precache`. I would like to have push notifications in my app, but I don't see any option to add `push` notification and `notification click` listeners via `sw-precache` generate.

Should I add some sort of concatenate after the files is generated?

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Currently push button on Chrome(version 70) is broken. Installed Canary and Jeff's approach worked for me. Spent couple of hours debugging in Chrome, hopefully this post will save time for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add in additional logic using the [`importScripts` option](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#importscripts-arraystring) in `sw-precache`.

For example, if you create a `push-listener.js` file with the following:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  // Your code here.
});
```

You can configure `sw-precache` to import it:

```
{
  importScripts: ['path/to/push-listener.js'],
  // Other sw-precache options here.
}
```

Comment: just to add to Jeff's reply. Caching and push notifications are separate things. So a tool like precache does nothing directly with push notifications.

Comment: Hi. I've added the script and imported it with importScript setting. I can run a console.log in the imported script but any EventListerns like this don't work. Does anyone know why the event listeners do not work?